# How to add sqlite command line tool to Docker aspnet:5.0-alpine image?

Tags: docker, sqlite, asp.net-core

I have docker image based on aspnet:5.0-alpine that I would like to add the sqlite3 command line tool so I can open a shell prompt and examine database files. I have tried adding these commands to my Dockerfile

```
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache sqlite-dev
```

but the image only contains the sqlite libraries, not the sqlite3 command line tool.

Is there a way to add the sqlite3 command tool to the image?

Answer (score 4):

The command line tool is in the `sqlite` package.

```
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache sqlite
```

Should add it.

Comment: Thanks @hans-kilian.  I was just going to answer my own question.  Your command is correct.  What I was doing wrong was I had the command in the wrong location of the Dockerfile. I needed to move closer to bottom so other commands wouldn't overwrite it.